# How would you run jasmine tests on a CI environment *without nodejs*

Tags: jenkins, jasmine

I have a bunch of jasmine tests that I would like to run on a jenkins CI server.

At the moment, we use an html page that runs the specs, that a developper can open in a browser on its own machine. 
The transition to CI would be easy if I had access to some kind of server side test runner (like karma), however for some undisclosable reasons, I can not run nodejs on our CI server.

So in the spirit of creativity-under-constraints, what could I use to automate jasmine tests without node ? (But anything that can run with maven and a jdk is probably fine...)

Comment: you dont disclose what CI solution or language your are using either...

Comment: @mpm : you're right, sorry. I edited my post - It's a jenkins server, and anything java-based should be fair game. Thanks.

Comment: can you run rhino ? since you use a jvm.

Comment: I need to test DOM manipulation, and as far as I can tell, rhino is just a javascript engine, not a headless browser, right ? I tried a bunch of solutions based on phantomjs, but I'm afraid I might not have access to a recent version...

Comment: no but i though rhino could launch karma. but obviously it doesnt have  nodejs api. What about ringoJS it runs on java maybe there are E2E solutions with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your test automatically spawn a browser with the page that runs your unit test. The tricky part tough is to get the result back to the main test runner. The solution that I have found for that is to use a custom jasmine reporter (you just need to implement the same function has to other reporter) and when a spec has finished to run you do an AJAX call to write that result in a file. The main runner just needs to wait until something is written in that file to see the results. Once the test are finish, just don't forget to kill the browser, otherwise your CI server will be flooded by window.